ADS1263 + ESP32-S3 PCB schematic
I am designing a four layer PCB with a TI 32-bit ADC (ADS1263) and an ESP32-S3-MINI-1U-N8. The aim is to use this board to read the output of an OPA197, which act as a buffer to a sensing resistor as explained here. I plan to use the JLC04161H-3313 stackup from JLCPCB. The board has also an FPC connector on the bottom side of the PCB to expose GPIO pins of the ESP32-S3. On the bottom side of the PCB, underneath the USB-C connector, there is also a DT1042-04SO ESD protection. I have tried to place the analog part of the ADC as far away as possible from PSU and digital components. The board will be supplied by a 12V input and then there are two voltage regulators (3.3V and 5V) since the ADS1263 needs also a 5V supply at the AVDD pin. The schematic and layout of the ADC part is inspired from TI eval board. The pins in J2 component would normally be connected via jumpers. I placed this in order to be able to connect the ADC to an external MCU or other GPIO pins in case I need to debug or test. Jumpers J1 and J3 are used to enable/disable power supply to the ADS1263.
Any feedback and criticism is really well appreciated and I have some questions:

Do you see anything wrong that I am doing in the schematic? Any tips for improvements?
What do you think about the placement I did for the ESD protection? Do you have better suggestions?
What do you think regarding the two LDOs (3.3V and 5V)? They are quite expensive but I have chosen them for their good PSRR.
Is the ESP32-S3-MINI-1U-N8 a good MCU for this purpose? It doesn´t have PSRAM built-in. Would you recommend to add external PSRAM for this application?

I place below some screenshot of the schematic and of the PCB's 3D view. I can add more pictures if requested.










What’s on your inner layers?

I have routed all tracks on top and bottom layers. The two inner layers are just ground plane.

What’s the purpose of JP2?

It´s a solder jumper that allows enabling/disabling pullup resistors at the SDA and SCL lines (I2C).

I will recomend to use the ESP32-S3 module instead of the heap as the shielding and a seperate PCB will help to isolate the adc from digital noises. Also go for the external antenna verson, it will not take up extra space if you are not using the wifi or bluetooth functionality. And if in future you wish to use it then you can route it outside of the metal housing it will be enclosed into.

Thanks for your comment. In this layout I intended to use the ESP32-S3-MINI-1U with uFL connector, thus without built in antenna for the reason you mentioned. However, I realized that this PCB is quite large and I wanted to start with something simpler first, so I am working on a new PCB with only the ADC (ADS1219) as described in this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/734120/correct-pcp-layout-for-ads1219-analog-and-digital-grounds
