Correct PCP layout for ADS1219 analog and digital grounds
I am designing my own PCB board for the ADS1219 24-bit ADC and I am following the BOOSTXL-ADS1219 Evaluation board design from TI. At page 18 and 19 of their user guide, it is shown the PCB layout of the two layers. Below I put screenshots of the area around the analog and digital ground connections. The digital ground pin (DGND) is not connected to the top layer. However, it is connected to the bottom layer together to the analog ground pin (AGND).

Top Layer TI Eval Board

Bottom Layer TI Eval Board
In my custom PCB design I am using a four-layer PCB board. I have made the layout as below using an exclusion zone to separate a bit the two grounds. The DGND is connected to the AGND only via the bottom layer, while on top and inner layers they are not connected. Do you agree with this layout or is there anything wrong? Do you have tips/suggestion for a better layout? I am honestly not sure if this is even needed and if it would be the same to just connect the two ground pine together on the top layer.

Top Layer - Custom PCB

Inner Layer B - Custom PCB

Inner Layer A - Custom PCB

Bottom Layer - Custom PCB
ADDITION:
Based on the suggestion from user bobflux I have modified the layout as below.

Edited version of the layout

Edited version of the layout - Full PCB. Ground inner layers (2 and 3) are hidden to show more clearly the first layer.
ADDITION 2:
Further improved version of the layout based on the suggestion from user bobflux.

Edited version 2 of the layout

The most important thing is to have the path with least inductance. This is accompliced best with a continues ground plane.

Bondwires, pins, and vias have impedance, which creates voltage drop when current flows.
The point of separate AGND and DGND pins is to avoid sharing this impedance between the chip's two internal ground nodes, which would allow voltage drop from DGND current to inject noise into AGND.
Thus it makes sense to go all the way and use two separate traces and vias for the two pins.
Thermal connections around vias increase impedance, which is a good reason to not use them.
Ground plane is usually on layer 2 so it can be closest to layer 1 which ensures minimum inductance for vias and decoupling capacitors, along with best shielding. If you replicate the ground plane on other layers there should be enough vias to stitch all the planes together to avoid the edge between these planes acting as antenna.
I assume the AGND copper pour on top layer is to provide shielding below the chip. Extending it further away may cause it to pick up noise and inject it into AGND, and it is also tempting to use it to connect other components to GND. This will cause common impedance coupling on the AGND via, so it is best to just keep this copper pour under the chip.
Ground plane impedance is extremely low. By introducing a cut between the AGND and DGND vias, you're probably trying to reduce noise, but it will increase the impedance of the ground plane at this spot and could increase noise instead.
Also remember an ADC performance is limited by noise and instability on its reference voltage. I see long traces from the reference pins, no idea where they're going to, but if you put a decoupling cap between REFP and REFN, it should be close. Likewise if you intend to connect REFN to GND this should be done with a via next to the AGND via. This is not done in the eval board because they bring REFP and REFN to sockets so the user can experiment, but on a finished product this won't be the case.

Thanks for the extremely detailed answer, I don´t get why it has been downvoted. Regarding lines to REFN and REFP, I will fix the PCB as per your suggestion. In the PCB I have used layer 2 and 3 as ground planes and routed signals in layer 1 and 4. Should I still connect both DGND and AGND to all four layers with the VIA? Also, in a first version of this PCB I did not have any cuts in the ground planes but I shorted the AGND and DGND together with a line connecting directly between the two ground pins. I guess this will increase the noise, right?

OK for ground on L2/L3 and signal on L3/L4, just add stitching vias. Just use normal vias for AGND/DGND, connecting to all ground layers. Yes if you connect grounds between the chip's pins, then the trace and via will be shared, that means more common impedance coupling and more noise.

I have modified the PCB trying to follow your recommendations. Is this what you meant? Regarding the stitching VIAs, did you mean something like this? I have added a full view of the PCB, if you have any other comments they will be very appreciated. For instance, is it a good or bad idea to have the mounting holes connected to ground? Below this PCB I plan to have another PCB (with ESP32-S3 MCU) with same size and same mounting holes connected to ground. So, if I use metallic PCB spacers, they will connect the analog side of the top PCB (with ADC) to the bottom PCB (with ESP32-S3).

OK, I see you splurged on vias ;) make sure they don't charge by the number of holes first! If your inputs are differential, as implied by C8 C10, it is best to have a symmetrical layout, notably the two caps to ground should connect to the ground plane at the same point, this gives better CMRR. Do not be afraid to use skinny traces and minimum spacing for your differential pairs, the closer the two signals in the pair are the better it is for CMRR. Decoupling caps for AVCC DVCC should be closer to the ADC chip.

If you put your pullup/pulldown resistors on the other side of the pin headers, then the traces will no longer criss cross and I guess you can do a clean layout with 2 layers. On the CLEAN_LDO pin header, instead of a jumper you can use a resistor. This will make a RC with the LDO input caps and filter the 5V supply to give better HF rejection. Since it's on a header you can try several values, see what works best. Also for test points I prefer pin headers, easier to catch with wire grippers, it frees one hand while testing.

Thanks again for the very instructive comments. I will make a modified version of the PCB based on your inputs. A question regarding the capacitors C8 and C10. I have placed them following the eval board from TI, but I guess I can still measure also single ended signals not only differential signals, right? For instance, if I want to measure a single signal between AIN0 and GND I can still keep C8/C10, right?

On single ended signals these caps will add a bit of crosstalk between the two inputs they're connected to, if your inputs are AC. If they're DC they shouldn't cause issues. You can still put the cap footprint on the board, then you can put the cap... or not...

Got it, thanks. I guess the same is valid for C3,C4,C5,C6, right? I can not populate them until I just measure single ended signals. As you saw the PCB layout has a jumper that allows selecting the 3.3V supply to AVDD between two options: 1) the 3.3V generated by ESP32 LDO that also supplies DVDD. 2) a separate LDO that is supposed to have much better PSRR. The LDO version is the ADM7150ARDZ-3.3-R7 from AD. Do you think it is a good choice to use this LDO to reduce noise? Another option would be to use the ADM7150ARDZ-5.0-R7 to generate 5V for AVDD but then I need to add a step-up converter.

I see one of C3-4-5-6 between each analog input and ground, these are fine for both single ended and differential. The crosstalk I was talking about is from C8 C10 which are between two analog inputs so they will leak one into the other if the signal is AC and single ended. The LDO has excellent PSRR, that's good. 3V3 from ESP32 should be pretty noisy due to the large supply current pulses it draws when using wifi.

Do you mean that it is worth using a high PSRR also for DVDD and avoid using the LDO which supplies the ESP32? In this case I would need to have two LDOs in this PCB to keep AVDD and DVDD separated. I am not sure also how advantageous would be to use a 5V LDO for AVDD instead of 3.3V. It would increase the dynamics range of the analog inputs of the ADC but I would then need to add a step-up converter to boost the input of this LDO from 5V to around 6V or 6.5V. And I am worried that this step-up converter would cause noise in the PCB.

For DVDD, probably not. Using 5V for AVDD you'd gain a tiny bit of dynamic range, probably not worth the effort and noise from DC-DC as you say. One important point is VREF, how is it generated?

At least initially I plan to use the internal reference. According to the datasheet of the ADS1219, it has an internal 2.048V Reference with 5 ppm/°C (typ) Drift. Do you think this is not sufficient to have accuracy in the order of 0.1mV in ADC output?

The internal reference is pretty good, it'll be hard to beat

Thanks a lot for all your very useful suggestions. I have added to the main post the latest iteration of the layout based on your comments. What do you think? Did I miss something? Unfortunately I cannot move the Pin header that will connect to the below PCB with ESP32 since that PCB is already sent for production, therefore I guess I'll have to stick to a four layer board for this.

It looks fine to me. You could squeeze the smaller caps closer to the chip, then that's it ;)

Thanks a lot. I have sent the PCB for manufacturing. My understanding is that if I use the built-in 2.048V reference I will not have a higher input dynamic range just by increasing AVDD from 3.3V to 5V, right? In order to take advantage of the higher analog supply voltage I would have to supply an external accurate voltage reference that is higher than 2.048V.

That is absolutely correct. A lot of work for 1 bit SNR improvement lol

The separation seems unnecessary. Yes you need a star connection to ensure signal integrity, but you wouldn't achieve it like that. The most important thing is to ensure the digital signal paths are not crossing the analog signals. So you can connect the grounds through all layers, but make sure your digital signals(don't forget about return paths) are not crossing your analog part of the PCB.

Thanks for your answer. I understand hence that I should completely remove the cuts I did on top and inner layers. In a first version of this PCB I did not have any cuts but I shorted the AGND and DGND together with a line directly between the two ground pins. I guess this will increase the noise, right?
